# How to add multiple classes to UL / LI elements in CSS3/jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I edited a template that I found online and had a jquery for thumbnails..

```
<ul class="ff-items">
<li class="ff-item-type-1">
    <a href="#" title="" >
        <div><span>Title 1 ABC</span></div>
        <img src="images/w_abc1.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="ff-item-type-3">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" >
        <div><span>TITLE 2 ABC</span></div>
        <img src="images/w_abc1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Link to this jquery plugin: [ [::Link::](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/09/filter-functionality-with-css3/) ]

This plugin groups a list of images and on hover displays an animation with spanned text for info. Basically a transition on hover.

Now, I'm trying to change the hover effect to another effect via another jquery plugin which uses the following syntax:

```
<ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
    <li>
        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/502538-Natalie-Justin-Cleaning">
            <img src="images/7.jpg" />
            <div><span>Natalie & Justin Cleaning by Justin Younger</span></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Link to this Jquery/CSS3 plugin: [ [:::link:::](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/) ]

Now, my problem is that I want to keep the radio button selection but don't want the transition effects on hover.. instead I want the second jquery listed above which displays the info in a direction-aware way.

Class for ul is already described as class="ff-items". How can I add another class to it? I tried giving a space between the classes but that didn't function at all. Images froze without any transition or hover effect at all! I tried this:

```
<ul id="da-thumbs" class="ff-items da-thumbs">
```

( added da-thumbs id and gave 2 classes to the UL.)

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: You have removed link to the first plugin right? Otherwise it'll create a conflict because both plugins will be trying to access the same dom object.

Comment: if I remove the link then the radio buttons won't work.... the plugin is required to select the radio buttons AND the hover effect. Is there a way to just keep the radio selection and disable hover 1 and enable hover 2 ??

Comment: I don't believe you would be able to do that. I guess you don't do the initialization manually and this is automatically done by the plugin for you by selecting the classes?

Comment: Well.. I just checked the source of plugin demo again.. The first plugin DOESN'T use jquery at all! It's all CSS based. It does use javascript **modernizr.custom.29473.js** though .... The second plugin uses jquery as follows: **modernizr.custom.97074.js, jquery.hoverdir.js, demo.css, style.css, and jquery script**: `$(function() { $(' #da-thumbs > li ').each( function() { $(this).hoverdir(); } ); });`

Comment: So, if the first plugin uses pure CSS for the effects then removing that class would stop the effects. But I suppose this would remove other effects/styles too. You'll have to look through the css for where it applies the hover effect. It'll be something like .className:hover { // styling here }. If you remove this bit then it should work the way you intend it to.

Comment: Well, the hover worked, but now the radio is not working... Primarily because I've put 2 classes in the UL: `<ul id="da-thumbs" class="ff-items  da-thumbs">` The hover is ok, but link to radios is not functioning.. it's plain text now, not clickable. Can I change the .da-thumbs {} class names to .ff-items {} ? Would that function then?